# How do i group user calender on button click using kendo scheduler in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, telerik-scheduler

i want to implement [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) functionality using RAZOR view engine. I want group the calender using user names which is present in resources of scheduler.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I didn't try so much in it. I am using Vertical Grouping " Group(group => group.Resources("CalenderUser"))" which is giving me Horizantal grouping. I was trying to use the check box and call the filter method on the checked event but it is sorting the events not giving the "Group" functionality.

Also i am using "drag and drop" which is working fine for single calender but not working for "Group of calender".I debugged it more then i realize the problem may be due to - after dropping event it won't understand which the owner of that calender. 
In scheduler control i am new - please guide me

Comment: You just have to add orientation to your code as below:      
**.Group(group => group.Resources("CalenderUser").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical))**

Comment: Also regarding the other question of Drag and drop, its better you create another question and tag appropriately so that you can get a better solution from the experts.

Comment: D_Learning  Sure i will create another question for this. 

The solution you have provided only gave me the vertical orientation instead of Horizontal. 

I need to group selected user calenders in kendo scheduler (means grouping after selecting checkbox)

Comment: i got this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-group-when-unchecking-resource) in which someone asked same question about group but ended up using "Filter" feature.

Please anyone help to achieve Grouping in slimier way.